# How to sort list of date object?

Tags: python

How to sort list of date object ?
For example I have unsorted list of date objects. How to get max/min value from this list ?

Comment: You don't have to sort to get min/max value, just use python builtin [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)/[max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) functions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the list [sort method](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
In [1]: from datetime import date, timedelta

In [2]: a=[date.today(), date.today() + timedelta(days=1), date.today() - timedelta(days=1)]

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
[datetime.date(2012, 3, 28),
 datetime.date(2012, 3, 29),
 datetime.date(2012, 3, 27)]

In [4]: a.sort()

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
[datetime.date(2012, 3, 27),
 datetime.date(2012, 3, 28),
 datetime.date(2012, 3, 29)]

In [6]: a[0] # min
Out[6]: datetime.date(2012, 3, 27)

In [7]: a[-1] # max
Out[7]: datetime.date(2012, 3, 29)
```

More on [how to sort](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Answer (score 6):

```
list.sort(key=lambda item:item['date'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Then all you have to do is get the first and last Item and you have you're MIN / MAX Dates