# Sorting Directories by creation time

Tags: python

I am logged into an ftp directory using `ftplib` and have listed the directories contained inside using:

> ftp.retrlines('LIST')

This is what it gives me in the terminal:

[image]

This list is in alphabetical order but i was wondering if there is any way to sort it by the dates given on the left?

I want to be able to sort it from newest to oldest.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
sorted = list()
dirs = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
times = list()
for dir in dirs:
    times.append(datetime.strptime(dir, '%m-%d-%y %I:%M%p'))
*sort times with some algorithm from python library* (pretty sure times.sort() should work but I cant say for sure
for i in range(0,len(times)):
    for dir in dirs:
        if dir.startswith(times[i]):
            sorted.append(dir)
            break
```

What Celeo said is right but will only give you the sorted times without the directories, this will give you both.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to turn the date strings into datetime objects, [then sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472795/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-datetime-or-date-objects).

```
d = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m-%d-%y %I:%M%p')
```