# Sorting dictionary by value by datetime in python

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, datetime

How do I sort a dictionary by value in datetime in shape of this:

```
{'user_0': [['item_805696', '2021-02-11 13:03:42'],
  ['item_386903', '2021-02-11 13:03:52'],
  ['item_3832', '2021-02-11 13:04:07'],
  ['item_849824', '2021-02-11 13:05:04'],
'user_1': [['item_97057', '2021-02-11 13:03:42'],
  ['item_644971', '2021-02-11 13:09:32'],
  ['item_947129', '2021-02-11 13:15:27'],
  ['item_58840', '2021-02-11 13:16:11'],
  ['item_640213', '2021-02-11 13:17:40'],
...
```

Im trying to sort values by datetime of second value in values of the dictionary

Comment: You have here how to sort by a dictionary value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value and here, how to sort by datetime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472795/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-datetime-or-date-objects. You can take that info to implement your solution

Comment: If the dates are in the the form of YYYY-MM-DD then you can sort them lexicographically. If not then you could convert them to datetime.datetime objects. Ironically, your data appear to be already in sorted order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a `key` to tell `list.sort` or `sorted` how to sort.

A key to sort by the first value is `lambda x: x[0]`; a key to sort by the second value is `lambda x: x[1]`.

```py
d = {'user_0': [['item_805696', '2021-02-11 13:03:42'],
                ['item_849824', '2021-02-11 13:05:04'],
                ['item_386903', '2021-02-11 13:03:52'],
                ['item_3832',   '2021-02-11 13:04:07']],
     'user_1': [['item_58840',  '2021-02-11 13:16:11'],
                ['item_947129', '2021-02-11 13:15:27'],
                ['item_97057',  '2021-02-11 13:03:42'],
                ['item_640213', '2021-02-11 13:17:40'],
                ['item_644971', '2021-02-11 13:09:32']]}

for v in d.values():
    v.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

print(d)
# {'user_0': [['item_805696', '2021-02-11 13:03:42'],
#             ['item_386903', '2021-02-11 13:03:52'],
#             ['item_3832',   '2021-02-11 13:04:07'],
#             ['item_849824', '2021-02-11 13:05:04']],
#  'user_1': [['item_97057',  '2021-02-11 13:03:42'],
#             ['item_644971', '2021-02-11 13:09:32'],
#             ['item_947129', '2021-02-11 13:15:27'],
#             ['item_58840',  '2021-02-11 13:16:11'],
#             ['item_640213', '2021-02-11 13:17:40']]}
```

Note that this only works because the timestamps are presented in the very practical format `'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'`, and strings are sorted lexicographically, i.e., from left to right. If the timestamps had been in a less friendly format, such as `'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS'`, then you'd need to use the key to parse the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this answer to convert the string representing the date to a number of seconds since the Unix epoch (1st January 1970): [How to convert python timestamp string to epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468371/how-to-convert-python-timestamp-string-to-epoch)

Then use can use the `key` argument of the `sorted` built-in method to use it to sort the dictionary how you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the datetime module in python standard librairy and here is the code

```
from datetime import datetime

d = {'user_0': [['item_805696', '2021-02-11 13:03:42'],
  ['item_386903', '2021-02-11 13:03:52'],
  ['item_3832', '2021-02-11 13:04:07'],
  ['item_849824', '2021-02-11 13:05:04']],
'user_1': [['item_97057', '2021-02-11 13:03:42'],
  ['item_644971', '2021-02-11 13:09:32'],
  ['item_947129', '2021-02-11 13:15:27'],
  ['item_58840', '2021-02-11 13:16:11'],
  ['item_640213', '2021-02-11 13:17:40']]}

def sort_by_datetime(val):
    return datetime.strptime(val[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

sorted_dict = {k: sorted(v, key=sort_by_datetime) for k, v in d.items()}
```